# Linking with a debug/release lib with qmake/Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I am using Qt Creator and have a Qt GUI project that depends on a C++ static library project.  I want to link the release version of the GUI app with the release build of the .lib and the debug release of the GUI app with the debug .lib.  I have found out how to add additional libraries to the project by including a line like the following in my .pro file:

`LIBS += -L./libfolder -lmylib.lib`

But I cannot see how I can use a different `-L` command for release and debug builds.

Is there support in qmake to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your project file you can do something like this

```
debug {
    LIBS += -L./libfolder -lmydebuglib.lib
}

release {
    LIBS += -L./libfolder -lmyreleaselib.lib
}
```

The bit inside the debug braces is used if DEBUG has been added to the CONFIG qmake variable, similarly stuff inside the release brackets is included if RELEASE has been added to the CONFIG variable.

You can also use "!debug" rather than "release" (i.e. when debug isn't in the config)

You can find more information on qmake [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html).

Comment: Note that it chokes if you put the brace on the next line...:-(

Comment: Is it the same for Windows too? What about if I have space in the paths of Lib files.

Answer (score 45):

The normal

```
debug:LIBS += ...
else:LIBS += ...
```

solution breaks when users naively use `CONFIG += debug` or `CONFIG += release` to switch between debug and release builds (and they do; no-one remembers to say `CONFIG -= release release_and_debug` before `CONFIG += debug` :).

This is the canonical way to scope on `debug`:

```
CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
    # debug
    QMAKE_LIBDIR += "path/to/debug/lib"
} else {
    # release
    QMAKE_LIBDIR += "path/to/release/lib"
}
```

Cf. [the qmake docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-test-function-reference.html#config-config).

**EDIT 2013-11-17**: Don't use `-Lfoo` in `LIBS`. The canonical way is to add the paths (without the `-L`) to `QMAKE_LIBDIR`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by canonical way, Marc? Someone without enough reputation is asking that in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511097/qt-qmake-libdir-vs-libs).

Comment: +1 because the "cannonical" form works both windows and linux. I was having a bit of trouble in Windows since using debug{} release{} was always linking to debug{} libs.