# Issue with Qt Creator LIBS path?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having a simple yet extremely annoying problem with adding the external library files in QtCreator. I'm adding them via the following lines in `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(D:/dcmtk-3.6.0/Prefix Files/include)

LIBS += $$quote(-LD:/dcmtk-3.6.0/Lib files/Release/) \
-ladvapi32 \
-ldcmdata\
-loflog\
-lofstd\
-lws2_32\
-lnetapi32\
-lwsock32\

LIBS += $$quote(-LD:/dcmtk-3.6.0/Lib files/Debug/) \
-ladvapi32 \
-ldcmdata\
-loflog\
-lofstd\
-lws2_32\
-lnetapi32\
-lwsock32\
```

But every time it's giving the error `:-1: error: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'files/Release).obj'`.

I know the problem is occuring because of the spaces there, despite trying to follow the documentation it doesn't seem to work. I also think that may be QtCreator doesn't update the changes I'm trying to make. Any suggestions please? Thanks.

**EDIT WITH SOLVED ANSWER:**

I changed the codes in .pro file to this:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = NewApp


##QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += /MTd

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
DEFINES += _REENTRANT


QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -MD
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -MT
QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG -= -MDd
QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG = -MTd
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -MD
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -MT
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG -= -MDd
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -MTd

QMAKE_LFLAGS_DEBUG += /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib

INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(D:/dcmtk-3.6.0/Prefix Files/include/)


CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
LIBS += $$quote(-LD:/dcmtk-3.6.0/LibFiles/Debug/) \
-ladvapi32\
-ldcmdata\
-loflog\
-lofstd\
-lws2_32\
-lnetapi32\
-lwsock32\
}


else {
LIBS += $$quote(-LD:/dcmtk-3.6.0/LibFiles/Release/) \
-ladvapi32\
-ldcmdata\
-loflog\
-lofstd\
-lws2_32\
-lnetapi32\
-lwsock32\
}
```

Here I had to add the lines:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS_DEBUG += /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
```

Because, if you turn on `MT`, you must use `/NODEFAULTLIB` switch to ignore these libraries: `libc.lib, msvcrt.lib, libcd.lib, libcmtd.lib, msvcrtd.lib`, otherwise you will get link problem.

And I also found the answer to `LIB` problems via this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130106/linking-with-a-debug-release-lib-with-qmake-qt-creator) where it's quoted:

"The normal

```
debug:LIBS += ...
else:LIBS += ...
```

solution breaks when users naively use `CONFIG += debug` or `CONFIG += release` to switch between debug and release builds (and they do; no-one remembers to say `CONFIG -= release` release_and_debug before `CONFIG += debug` :).

This is the canonical way to scope on debug:

```
CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
    # debug
} else {
    # release
}
```

"

Anyways, thanks a lot.

Comment: maybe try to change LIBS line to LIBS += $$quote(D:/dcmtk-3.6.0/Lib\ files/Release/) \

Comment: Does it work if you actually put quote characters around them?

Comment: I've updated my question with a solution that I found :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to specify library link locations in a .pro file is actually via the `QMAKE_LIBDIR` variable:

```
QMAKE_LIBDIR += "D:/dcmtk-3.6.0/Lib files/Release/"
```

Your issue above is almost certainly because of missing quotes (the space is being interpreted as a argument break and you need it to be one argument).

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen yours before I found a solution. But I have updated question with a solution include. :)

Comment: But I'd like to ask you another question if you may know. If I want set several files together to ignore in `/NODEFAULTLIB` is there any way I can do it in one line? Or I have to do it in several line?