# Qt - QMAKE_LIBDIR vs LIBS

Tags: qt, qmake

One can find a lot of examples where QMAKE_LIBDIR is used to specify additional library directories.

The Qt manual says:

> QMAKE_LIBDIR
>
> Specifies a list of system library paths. The value of this variable is typically handled by qmake or qmake.conf and rarely needs to be modified.

Up to now I always used "unix: -L$$(LIB_DIR) -l" or similar whenever I wanted to use an external library in one of my projects and didn't want to use the library wizard.

Can I conclude that specifying a path via -L is discouraged even if there is no corresponding statement within the manual? (According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1130184/3115608) it is discouraged - but why?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a way there's a corresponding statement. Put your `-Lpath/to/dir` into the `LIBS` variable:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs

> LIBS
>
> Specifies a list of libraries to be linked into the project. If you
>   use the Unix -l (library) and -L (library path) flags, qmake handles
>   the libraries correctly on Windows (that is, passes the full path of
>   the library to the linker). The library must exist for qmake to find
>   the directory where a -l lib is located.
>
> For example:
>
> unix:LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lmath
>
> win32:LIBS += c:/mylibs/math.lib

So, using `-L` within `LIBS` is actually encouraged by the Qt docs

Comment: May be it'll be useful for someone, but when I added just `win32:LIBS += path/to/lib` I got the error "Permission denied". Adding `-L` before path fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `QMAKE_LIBDIR` externally without editing of `*.pro` file unlike from `LIBS`:

`qmake QMAKE_LIBDIR=~/build/obj/`